# Как найти фамилию и номер из контактов?

Tags: java, android

Моя задача состоит в том чтобы получить имя фамилию и номер телефона абонента.
Вот так я получаю все значения, кроме фамилии.

Фамилии в `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.` просто нету.

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idPhone = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int idName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int idContact = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
        String phone = cursor.getString(idPhone);
        String name = cursor.getString(idName);
        String id = cursor.getString(idContact);
```

---

На SO Нашел такой ответ. Он тоже рабочий.
Я не хочу делать 2 запроса по всему списку, чтобы получить номера, а потом и фамилию. Это занимает много времени.

Можно ли как - то объединить эти 2 запроса? Запрос на получения номеров и имени с фамилией

```
String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    Cursor nameCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
    while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
        String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
        String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
        String display = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    nameCur.close();
```